# Navigation Menu not shown

Tags: android, android-layout, drawerlayout

This is my `drawermenu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_one"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
        android:title="Rate the App" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_two"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
        android:title="Contact Us" />

</menu>
```

And this is my main activity xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            app:titleTextColor="#000000"
            android:background="#008B8B"
            app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            style="@style/CardView.Light"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <!--android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="314dp"-->

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2">

                <!--  android:id="@+id/cardView2"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="231dp">-->

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="92dp"
                    android:layout_height="92dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/twealth"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView"
                    android:layout_width="196dp"
                    android:layout_height="49dp"
                    android:text="HSC Board"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="46dp"
                    android:text="Maharashtra State Board"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/arrowBtn"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/arrowBtn"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <!--  <LinearLayout
                      android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView">

                      <LinearLayout
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:orientation="horizontal">

                          <TextView
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:text="@string/good_morning" />

                      </LinearLayout>
                  </LinearLayout>-->

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/expandableView"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                <!-- <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView"
                    android:layout_width="356dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="109dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />-->

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/openhsc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                    android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
                    android:text="OPEN HSC PAPERS"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/space2"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/space2" />

                <Space
                    android:id="@+id/space2"
                    android:layout_width="366dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/Navview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
        >
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

    <!-- <Button app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"

        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="336dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        android:text="@string/engineering"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.493"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />-->

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Actually I think this error is causing because I am using two menus at same time, but I don't know what is happening actually.

Along with this I am using one more menu which I am using for overflow menu.
that file is sidemenu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!--    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">-->

        <item
            android:id="@+id/mShare"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
            android:title="Share App"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            ></item>


<!--    </group>-->

</menu>
```

But when I do gravity_layout_Start  remove from the navigation view it shows the menu items that is strange for me. Can you solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `NavigationView` change `tools:menu="@menu/drawermenu"` to `app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"`.